# laravelのauthenticationについて

Tags: laravel

```
php artisan make:auth
```

にて、authenticationを作りました。
urlで何を入力すれば、login, registerの表示されているページに、飛ぶのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

laravelのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

```
php artisan make:auth
```

を使うのでしたら5.8以前とお見受けします。
[5.8の公式ドキュメント](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.8/ja/authentication.html)には以下のように書かれていますが試されましたか？

> Tip!! さくっと始めたいですか？ インストールしたばかりのLaravelアプリケーションで、`php artisan make:auth` と `php artisan migrate` を実行するだけです。次に、ブラウザで `http://your-app.test/register` 、もしくはアプリケーションに割りつけたその他のURLへアクセスしてください。この２つのコマンドが、認証システム全体のスカフォールドを面倒みます。